# call A function is slow

Tags: vb.net

I have following function in my vb 2005 project

```
Public Function Getrawmatstockwdate(ByVal Partno As String, ByVal Loc As String, ByVal Tgl As Date) As Double 
    Using con = Openconnection()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            Dim Stockbal As Decimal = 0.0
            cmd.CommandText = "select round(ifnull(sum(stk.qty),0)," & Decimalpoint & ") from (select op_qty as qty from location where matcode='" & _
            Partno & "' and location='" & Loc & "' union all select in_qty as qty from min_in_body inner join min_in_head on min_in_body.doc_no=min_in_head.doc_no " & _
            "and min_in_body.entry_no=min_in_head.entry_no where matcode='" & Partno & "' and location='" & Loc & "' and in_date<='" & Tgl.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & _
            "' union all select (-1*out_qty) as qty from min_out_body inner join min_out_head on min_out_body.doc_no=min_out_head.doc_no where matcode='" & Partno & _
            "' and location='" & Loc & "' and out_date<='" & Tgl.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "') stk
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = con
            Stockbal = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            Return Stockbal
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

And i call it from other form that consist a gridview (dgView has 50000 records)

```
    For i as integer=0 to dgView.RowCount - 1         
        dgView.Item(7, i).Value = Getrawmatstockwdate(dgView.Item(0, i).Value, dgView.Item(5, i).Value, dtTo.DateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    Next
```

It can takes upto 30 minutes plus, but if put the function directly to looping (as below code) it takes only 5 minutes, anyone care to explain why?

```
For i as integer = 0 to dgView.RowCount - 1 
        Dim Partno As String = dgView.Item(0, i).Value
        Dim Loc As String = dgView.Item(5, i).Value
        'get bal qty
        Dim Stockbal As Decimal = 0.0
        cmd = New MySqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "select round(ifnull(sum(stk.qty),0)," & Decimalpoint & ") from (select op_qty as qty from location where matcode='" & _
        Partno & "' and location='" & Loc & "' union all select in_qty as qty from min_in_body inner join min_in_head on " & _
        "min_in_body.doc_no=min_in_head.doc_no " & "and min_in_body.entry_no=min_in_head.entry_no where matcode='" & Partno & _
        "' and location='" & Loc & "' and in_date<='" & dtTo.DateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' union all select (-1*out_qty) as qty " & _
        "from min_out_body inner join min_out_head on min_out_body.doc_no=min_out_head.doc_no where matcode='" & Partno & _
        "' and location='" & Loc & "' and out_date<='" & dtTo.DateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "') stk"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        Stockbal = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        dgView.Item(7, i).Value = Stockbal            
    Next
```

Hopefully it is readable. Don't know how to format it in stackoverflow.

Comment: why would you load 50000 rows into a gridview? Don't.

Comment: 'cause you don't open a connection to the db each time. You can pass a Connection as a parameter.

Comment: And you should also use a parameterised query

Comment: What is parameterised query, thanks for the explanation before. Is it something like cmd.parameter.addvalue?